# Error sending mail from Asp.Net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have built a feedback page.I am trying to send mail from the page.The client provided me with the `SMTP Server` name , `Email ID` and `Password`.But when I try to send mail from the page I am getting following error.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 64.37.118.141:25

Here is my code

```
MailMessage feedBack = new MailMessage();

//feedBack.To.Add("master@myclient.com");
feedBack.From = new MailAddress("master@myclient.com");
feedBack.Subject = "Mail from Explor Corporate Website.";  
feedBack.Body = "Sender Name: " + Name.Text + "<br/><br/>Sender Last Name:"+LastName.Text+"<br/><br/>Sender Company:"+Company.Text+"<br/><br/>Sender Designation"+Designation.Text+"<br/><br/>Sender Email:"+Email.Text+"Sender Phone No:"+ PhoneNo.Text+"Sender Enquiry:"+Enquiry.Text;
feedBack.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.myclient.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
//smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("master@myclient.com", "*****");
//Or your Smtp Email ID and Password

smtp.Send(feedBack);
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This most likely indicates you don't have either the correct host name, or the correct port.

If you are using SSL then the default SMTP port which is 25 will not work. I noticed that you did have a line setting the port what was commented out.

Try setting the port to 587 and if that doesn't work, try port 465 which is sometimes used for secure SMTP.

If that doesn't work either confirm with your client the correct port and host name..

And another thing you may want to double check is whether the SMTP server you are using does indeed support/require SSL. If it does not support SSL that you will need to set the `EnableSSL` option to false and try connecting on the default port of 25 (or whatever port they are using).

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but there was an error for port 587 and for 465 , also I tried setting port 25 and enableSSL to false.The result was the same , so do you think the smtp server name that the client gave me is wrong , because the credentials are right.

Comment: Either that, or there is a firewall that is not configured correctly between the machine you are using to send e-mails and the SMTP server. It could be on your end or on their end, blocking communications on the port your are using.

Comment: I sent mail using gmail it worked , so do you think firewall can be an issue.Thanks.

Comment: @freebird - what do you mean you sent mail using gmail? Did you send mail from that machine running ASP.NET using a Gmail account? If so then yeah, I would make sure the host name your were provided with is correct and that they don't have a firewall blocking the necessary ports (at the server's site)

Comment: I sent mail from my machine runnning ASP.NET using gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible timeout error or authentication problem. When accessing external resources from code you will need to handle possible errors:

```
try
{
 smtp.Send(feedBack); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // Handle the exception here
}
```