# Failure sending mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make an email page section and I found an article and one of the answer in this forum which I used in my codes below but its still saying failure sending mail which I could hardly figure out why?. I need assistance in finding a remedy why my codes below fails to send an email. Here my codes below for your reference. Please advise...Thanks.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        client.Host = "smtp.live.com"; //Im not sure about this,I just copy it from the article
        client.Port = 4548; //This is my ASP.Net Development Server Port,Im not sure also if this is correct.

        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
            @"email_account",
            @"email_password"); //Im not sure about this code if this correct, I just copy it


        client.EnableSsl = true;

        // create message
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(TextBox4.Text, "Mackmellow"); //Textbox4 is my email address
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TextBox1.Text, "Mackmellow")); // Textbox1 is the email add I want to send
        message.Subject = TextBox2.Text; //Textbox2 is my subject
        message.Body = TextBox3.Text; // Textbox3 is my message
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;


        // send message
        try
        {
            client.Send(message);


        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {

            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clean up.
            message.Dispose();
        }
```

Can please correct my codes and tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the actual error message (and/or inner exception) you get?  "Failure sending mail" is as general as telling the auto mechanic "Car won't run".  More detail is always a good thing :)

Comment: Is there an error with the failure?

Comment: you have to make sure that your email (from_email) belongs to the email provider (in your case "smtp.live.com") otherwise it will fail, also, your port is incorrect, it should be whatever live.com is accepting smtp on

Comment: How do I know that my email belongs to email provider "smtp.live.com"? My email is @gmail.com is that belong to "smtp.live.com"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending mail you can't use your development server port.

You have to use the smtp server port of your mail server.

for smtp.live.com you should use either port 25 or  587

For this code below, specify VALID login details (email/password)

```
  client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
            @"email_account",
            @"email_password");
```

Comment: I tried to use both ports 25 and 587 respectively but it still display an error message saying 'Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated'

Comment: You have to specify valid username/password combination in the network credentials ... modify the values you copied :)

Comment: Is that my email address or the email address I want to sent to?

Comment: that should be the email address your are sending from? and it should contain the password as well, that is why you are having authentication issues. smtp.live.com isn't able to authenticate the values you supplied. Please supply valid values and all will be well :)

Comment: I tried to modify the values of the email account and password but still giving a message:  'Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated'. Why is it so?

Comment: If your email is gmail.com, you should use smtp.gmail.com and not smtp.live.com

Comment: ,,,Thank you very much I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Provide only G-mail  Account Id.Then check it . I think `SmtpClient` Does not accept any other domain mail address . So you can put only  `gmail` address then check it .

Edit

See this sample's and other answers .

[Error sending mail from Asp.Net/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265376/error-sending-mail-from-asp-net-c)

[how to send email in asp.net to any destination eg yahoo,gmail,hotmail etc c# code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/05220933-8305-4295-87d2-519865838e13/)

Comment: Yes Ramesh, In fact in the From section I used my email address which is @gmail.com and I verified also the correct password in my code but still giving the same error.

Comment: but the address I am sending is @yahoo.com

Comment: Hai Check this sample

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659210/unable-to-send-email-to-other-domains-using-system-net-mail-smtpclient

Comment: Please see my Edit answer.Its helping to you .

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("email@hotmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("ToGmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Your Sub";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    string htmlBody;
    htmlBody = "HTML code";
    mail.Body = htmlBody;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@hotmail.com", "YourPassword");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use your code but still gives me a runtime exception. This is the error message: Server Error in '/WebSite1' Application.

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated